# Css calculated amount

Tags: css, stylus

How do I set both width and height based on proportions of the width. Here's what I'm talking about:

```
.foo
   height: total_width * 0.10
   width: 10%
```

If I set `height: 10%` it would calculate that based on 100% height, and I want to have height as 10% of 100% width

If it's not possible with css is it possible in Stylus?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can be possible using viewport units: vh, vw, vmin, and vmax.  Older browsers do not support these and if this functionality is critical you can use an appropriate shim (see http://html5polyfill.com/).